# Serving static files in Node.js using node-static

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-static

I put together a rudimentary Node app and am trying to avoid unnecessary dependencies (most notably `express`) for educational purposes. However, I've been running into an issue trying to serve up static files such as images or css. For security reasons, I've opted for node-static over coding my own version, but I can't seem to hook things up properly.

**File structure**

```
index.js
router.js
server.js
requestHandlers.js
package.json
views/
  index.jade
public/
  image.jpg
```

**Index**

```js
var server = require("./server"),
    router = require("./router"),
    requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {
  "/": requestHandlers.index
};

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

**requestHandlers**

```js
var jade = require("jade");

function index(response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  var body = jade.renderFile("views/index.jade");
  response.write(body);
  response.end();
}

exports.index = index;
```

**server**

```js
var http = require("http"),
    url  = require("url"),
    static = require("node-static"),
    port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8888);

var fileServer = new static.Server("./public");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    // NODE STATIC CODE - NOT WORKING
    request.addListener('end', function () {
      fileServer.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();

    // ROUTE HANDLING - WORKING
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    route(handle, pathname, response);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);
}

exports.start = start;
```

**router**

```js
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
  if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
    console.log("Request handler " + pathname + " was called.");
    handle[pathname](response);
  } else {
    console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("404 Not Found");
    response.end();
  }
}

exports.route = route;
```

Finally, my index file calls out `img(src="public/image.jpg")`, although I've also tried just `image.jpg` and `public/image`. The `/` route is being called and handled appropriately, but when the index file attempts to load the image the `else` block of my request handler is hit (as expected, since I don't have a route for it) and nothing else happens. Could someone please explain the proper way to use `node-static` in this case?

Comment: I think you could get more answers by asking how to make your code work, or why it isn't working instead of what the proper way to use the lib is.

Comment: I think your code is not working because your router is writing the `404 not found` response before `node-static` gets a chance to respond, btw. :)